# Elminar un registro en laravel 10 y disparar un evento SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert2, delete

Tengo un detalle al tratar de eliminar un registro en mis tablas, dentro del loop agregue un formulario solo para el botón de eliminar y la ruta que se genera con cada botón si genera el id correcto por cada fila pero al llegar al controlador siempre sale el id del primer registro de la tabla, por lo tanto siempre me elimina el registro que esta hasta arriba de la tabla sin importar a cual registro de clic.

**Este es el script swal**

```
    <script>

    function confirmDelete() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: "¿Estas seguro?",
            text: "!No podrás revertir esta acción!",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#b91c1c",
            cancelButtonColor: "#4338ca",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar!",
            customClass: {
                title: 'text-black',
                confirmButton: 'btn-danger',
                cancelButton: 'btn-primary',
            }
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Este es el loop**

```
 @foreach ($requisitionTypes as $requisitionType)
                <tr
                    class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                    <th scope="row"
                        class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                        {{ $requisitionType->name }}
                    </th>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">

                        <a href="{{ route('requisition-types.edit', $requisitionType) }}"
                            class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-200 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white dark:text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-white focus:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:bg-white active:bg-gray-900 dark:active:bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800 transition ease-in-out duration-150">Editar</a>

                        <form action="{{ route('requisition-types.destroy', $requisitionType) }}" method="POST" class="py-2" id="delete-form">
                            @csrf @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-200 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white dark:text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-white focus:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:bg-white active:bg-gray-900 dark:active:bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800 transition ease-in-out duration-150" onclick="confirmDelete()">
                                Eliminar
                            </button>
                            @dump(route('requisition-types.destroy', $requisitionType))
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
  @endforeach
```

En el controlador es desde donde disparo el swal mediante un session

**Esta es la parte del controllador que se encarga de eliminarlo**

```
    public function destroy(RequisitionType $requisitionType)
{

    $requisitionType->delete();

    session()->flash('swal', [
        'title' => '!Bien hecho!',
        'text' => 'Tipo de requisición eliminado correctamente',
        'icon' => 'success',
        'customClass' => [
            'title' => 'text-black',
            'confirmButton' => 'btn-primary',
        ]
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('requisition-types.index');
}
```

Supongo que tiene algo que ver con el código de javascript y como estoy enviando los datos como dato curioso si cambio el boton a tipo submit en ves de tipo button si elimina el registro que estoy eligiendo pero lo elimina automaticamente antes de que le de confirmar al boton de la ventana emergente de swal

Comment: falta contexto, uno de los errores comunes es tener varios elementos con el mismo id, puedes validar eso ... si por casualidad todos los form tienen el mismo id o botones o campos hay id duplicados... es normal que el sistema envie siempre el primero ... lo ideal seria generar id o names con valores distintos, secuenciados o referenciados ...

Comment: por otro lado no entiendo la logica con la que envias los datos y quieres mostar el SweetAlert2... o es una cosa o es otra pero no al mismo tiempo... incluso si refrescas la pantalla con el submit jamas tendras una respuesta para la alerta en el mismo sitio a menos que implemente un mecanismo pos-request ... que implemente un mecanismo de perseverancia por session y este indique que habia pendiente un mensaje de resultado de accion ...

Comment: validé los botones de cada fila y cada si genera la ruta correcta, en cuanto a la lógica que comentas en el layout principal es donde tengo el script del swal ( de confirmacion) que se activa al pulsar el botn de eliminar una vez que le de aceptar se envía el formulario y lo recibe el controlador donde elimina y una vez hecho mando un session flash que al retornar al index lo recibo con este fragmento de cogido y ya muestra la alerta de eliminación exitosa que mando desde el controlador `@if (session('swal'))
<script>
    Swal.fire({!! json_encode(session('swal')) !!});
</script>
@endif`

Comment: que por supuesto perfectamente me puedo estar complicando de mas y hay una forma super sencilla de hacerlo por eso pongo mi duda aquí

Comment: bueno si ya te funciona como esperas puedes responderte a ti mismo y cuando marques la pregunta como respondida ganaras reputacion, por otro lado ... el si hay otra forma de hacerlo, estoy seguro que si ... pero ese tipo de preguntas no son muy bien recibidas en el sitio... ya que suelen estar basadas en opiniones y se prestan para discucion ... sin embargo si tienes un ejemplo funcional minimo reproducible ... puedes y sabes que mejoras quisieras hacer... puedes ir a preguntarlas en code review, que es el sitio que se dedica a eso. pero esta en ingles.

Comment: entiendo‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mi el error está en que no le estás poniendo el ->id al route.

Asi lo estas poniendo tu:

```
<form action="{{ route('requisition-types.destroy', $requisitionType) }}" method="POST" class="py-2" id="delete-form">
                            @csrf @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-200 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white dark:text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-white focus:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:bg-white active:bg-gray-900 dark:active:bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800 transition ease-in-out duration-150" onclick="confirmDelete()">
                                Eliminar
                            </button>
                            @dump(route('requisition-types.destroy', $requisitionType))
                        </form>
```

Sustituye

```
{{ route('requisition-types.destroy', $requisitionType) }}
```

por

```
{{ route('requisition-types.destroy', $requisitionType->id) }}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos y Dios te bendiga.

Comment: Gracias por la idea pero ya lo intente y tampoco funciona, en esta versión de laravel ya no es necesario ponerle el ->id ya entiende por defecto que lo que quieres es eso y repito que le hice un dump a cada ruta generada por cada uno de los formularios y si esta generando las rutas correctas no repite ningún id.... otra opción que me sugirió chat gpt es que no le estaba pasando ningún argumento a la función confirmDelete que ahí debía poner el id del registro, también lo intente y deja de funcionar el botón